# Windows 10 system stuck in a boot loop

Tags: windows-10

I did a system recovery on my Asus G11CD i5 Laptop and then every time I try to boot up I get an error message that says Windows didn't load correctly. It then gives me a list of options. It looks like my hard drive isn't working correctly because it says it can't find it but I can't be for sure because it is a brand new computer. I have run "chkdsk /f" but it does not resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bad sector at the beginning of the disk, Try partitioning the disk and choose the second partition for windows installation.

Comment: How my computer only goes into "Windows didn't load correctly "

Comment: I see.. use an installation media.. a setup Cd or flash

Answer (score 0):

There is a high chance that the boot sectors have corrupted. Fortunately, you can repair it however you will need to boot into the recovery partition on the laptop (usually using one of the function "F" keys) or with a Windows install disk.

Step 1: Press F8 while booting the system to go into the Windows Recovery Menu. Unlike other version Windows 8’s recovery menu has the Metro UI style.

Step 2: Click on Troubleshoot.

Step 3: Click on Advanced options to get into Automatic Repair menu.

Step 4: We need to use the Bootrec.exe tool. Click on command prompt and type in the following commands, one after the other:

- bootrec /RebuildBcd
- bootrec /fixMbr
- bootrec /fixboot
- Exit

Now go ahead and reboot your system. In some cases you may need to run: "bootsect /nt60 SYS" or "bootsect /nt60 ALL".

Comment: It didn't work I get the same error after I typed all of that these are all the screens I get http://m.imgur.com/DCF10E3,R03Tisa,1ZOBken,YGPVDF8,G9Mc0B6,FWGtrE1

Comment: There will be an option in there to enter the command prompt, you need to enter the commands in there.

Comment: I typed it in it (command prompt)said it works but it didn't do anything

Comment: You mentioned that this is a brand-new laptop, correct? The laptop should have a built-in recovery partition where it restores an image to the system partition. Have you tried that?

Comment: OMG I didn't mean to type laptop it's a tower. But what do you mean by built in partition

Comment: Ok, seeing as how it is a full-size and not a laptop, then it probably won't have a recovery partition. Can you take a photo of the error it is giving you?

Comment: I did its one of the images

Comment: Did you "Reset This PC"?

Comment: Ok, you will then need physical media to run Startup Repair on your PC.

1) Start your computer from the installation media, Insert the DVD or USB flash drive and restart your computer, If you see a message asking you to “Press any key to boot from DVD,” do so. If you don’t see the message, you might need to change the boot order in your computer's BIOS settings so that it first starts from the DVD or USB. When you see the Install Windows page, tap or click Repair your computer to start the Windows Recovery Environment.

Comment: I have a Windows 7 disk

Comment: 2) In the Windows Recovery Environment, on the Choose an option screen, tap or click Troubleshoot. 3) Tap or click, advanced options and then click on Startup repair. You need a Windows 10 disk which can be downloaded from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10?ppud=4

Comment: Would I need a usb or can I download this on the computer

Comment: You can create a bootable flash drive or burn the ISO to a blank DVD. You can't copy it to the PC.

Comment: can you explain what you mean by a bootable flash drive like do I just drop the file in and boom it's bootable

Comment: Here is how you can make one: http://bfy.tw/3eRI